# "Demand " as a parts of speech

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, parts-of-speech

In the following sentence

> The information is important to demand attention from all levels of
>   organization

what type of parts of speech is **demand**??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it's a simple question to answer. "Demand" there is a verb.

Comment: Could you provide the source of the sentence?

Comment: I'm sorry to say the main sentence was "The information is important enough to demand frequent and regular attention from all levels of the organization.

Comment: Strategic management creating competitive advantages by Gregory G. Dess and others :sixth edition. page 363.@userr2684291

Answer (score 1):

In that case, *demand* is being a verb - in this case, the infinitive.

*Demand* can also be a noun, essentially meaning "what is demanded" or a communication in which a person is demanding something.

I'm having trouble working out what the sentence as a whole is getting at, but that isn't relevant to your question as asked.